# Docker Autoreload with CompileDaemon

Tags: docker, go

I am working on trying to improve my development environment using Docker and Go but I am struggling to get auto reloading in my containers working when there is a file change.  I am on Windows running Docker Desktop version 18.09.1 if that matters.

I am using CompileDaemon for reloading and my DockerFile is defined as follows

```
FROM golang:1.11-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates git
RUN go get github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/testrepo/app
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT CompileDaemon -log-prefix=false -directory="." -build="go build /go/src/github.com/testrepo/app/cmd/api/main.go" -command="/go/src/github.com/testrepo/app/main"
```

My project structure follows

- app

  - api

    - main.go

In my docker-compose file I have the correct volumes set and the files are being updated in my container on when I make changes locally.

The application is also started correctly using CompileDaemon on its first load, its just not ever updated on file changes.

On first load I see...

> Running build command! 
> Build ok. 
> Restarting the given command.

Then any changes I make are not resulting in a restart even though I can connect to the container and see that the changes are reflected in the expected files.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have **volumes** mounted for the services you are using, it is what makes the hot reloading work inside of a Docker container

[See the full explanation](https://www.zachjohnsondev.com/posts/go-docker-hot-reload-example)

Answer (score 0):

Proper way of installing the Compile Daemon is

```
RUN go install -mod=mod github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon
```

Reference: https://github.com/githubnemo/CompileDaemon/issues/45#issuecomment-1218054581